# PHP error handling from .NET web service?

Tags: php, .net, web-services, error-handling

Im using a php web form to insert product registrations into a .NET published web service. My insertXmlData function works, but I'm having trouble with error handling. When I attempted to insert a record with an already existing serial number Im getting this returned:

```
ERROR-5002 - Unique serial number must not be blank System.Exception
```

I tried this:

```
    try   
    {   
        $xmlData = insertXmlData($url, $xml);  
    }   
    catch (Exception $e)   
    {   
        echo ("Triggered");
        throw new Exception( 'There was an error...', 0, $e);   
    }
```

But the catch clause doesn't even trigger. Is it a .NET to php thing or is my syntax incorrect?  What's my best option for handling errors in this situation?

Comment: It sounds like the internal code within insertXmlData() is throwing a real (vs user triggered) PHP error.  PHP try catch blocks are notorious for not catching PHP errors like that.  What are you using internally to call the web service?

Comment: A curl function, says its too long to post in comments.

Comment: // here's the core of it   
'curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $targetUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cardxml);
$output = curl_exec($ch);'